# Why is this htaccess redirect reporting as a temporary redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect, web, hosting

I'm in the middle of an SEO audit and noticed that certain pages are being reported as temporary redirects as opposed to permanent redirects. I'm sure this is coming from the redirect setup from HTTP to HTTPS.

Here is the redirect in from the .htaccess file.

```
# website www redirect
RewriteEngine On
rewritecond %{http_host} ^example.com
rewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Can anybody tell me if this is implemented incorrectly to be a permanent redirect for HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

Per https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r :

> Any valid HTTP response status code may be specified, using the syntax [R=305], with a 302 status code being used by default if none is specified.

So in your second block of configuration, the `R` in `[R,L]` is a temporary redirect (code `302`). Change it to `R=301` if you want a permanent redirect, or clearer `R=permanent`.

Also, for simple redirections you do not need `mod_rewrite`, just look at the `Redirect` directive, or its wrappers: `RedirectTemp` and `RedirectPermanent`, from the `mod_alias` module (see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)